# Zernike Moments' implementation in OpenCV

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, opencv, local-features, shape-analysis

The reason why Hu moments were implemented in OpenCV and why Zernike moments were not implemented is looking like their performance similar as stated in [this paper](http://www.smartcr.org/view/download.php?filename=smartcr_vol3no3p3.pdf).

As stated in the paper Zernike moments' advantage is their reconstruction facility.

If there is a reliable implementation of Zernike moments compatible with OpenCV I would like to test their shape matching performance with [OpenCV's Hu moments shape matching](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#matchshapes) performance and if possible reconstruction facility.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used the Zernike module from [PeRL](http://robots.engin.umich.edu/)'s myself, but check out their implementation [here](https://robots.engin.umich.edu/svn/perls/branches/acfr/src/perls-vision/).

It's written as an OpenCV module and looks well optimized.

**However**! I have no idea what their license on this is, so definitely check before you integrate it into anything you're going to distribute or sell.

Comment: Thank you @Phonon. I will check it. Thanks for remarking license.